# glGetError returns invalid operation - not within Begin/End

Tags: opengl

right at the begin of my _tWinMain function i call twice glGetError()

both return 1282 (invalid operation)

the manual says that the function generates invalid operation error if it's called within Begin/End, but this is not the case here.

Is it only legal to call glGetError after some steps were performed (like initializing context or something like that) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glGetError returns the error state of the currently bound OpenGL render context. If there is no context bound, the result of calling glGetError are undefined, i.e. it's a invalid operation at that point.

Comment: okay. so, one more question: what does it mean when wglMakeCurrent returns TRUE, but sets the error to "invalid operation" ?

Comment: Are you completely sure wglMakeCurrent sets invalid operation error, not some other OpenGL call?